# Krein-Milman in non locally convex space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

In the book "Functional analysis and semi-groups" by Hille and Phillips, the Krein-Milman theorem (p. 28, Theorem 2.6.4) is stated as follows:

> Let $X$ be a TVS such that the topological dual $X'$ separates points (i.e. for any $x \in X$, $x \neq 0$, there is some $\phi \in X'$ with $\phi(x) \neq 0$). Then any compact, convex set $C \subseteq X$ is the closed convex hull of its extreme points.

No proof is given, only a reference to a paper of Kelley

> J. L. Kelley, Note on a theorem of Krein and Milman, J. Osaka Inst. Sci. Tech. Part I 3 (1951)

which I cannot access. 
However other books that refer to the same paper always assume local convexity of the space $X$. 
Also the usual proof of Krein-Milman (for locally convex TVS) needs Hahn-Banach, which in its weakest geometric form assumes that the interior of one of the convex sets is non-empty, which the closed convex hull of $C$ does not need to be.

So my question is:

> It the above theorem true? If yes, is is there any accessible reference where it is proven?

Comment: If you have Rudin's _Functional Analysis_ or can easily access it, it's Theorem 3.23 there. Rudin's assumption is just that the dual separates points. It can easily be derived from the theorem for locally convex spaces. I can do that in an answer if you want.

Comment: @DanielFischer Just a minute ago I looked in Rudin and saw that. I guess one always has to look into the classics first... Thank you.